# Forward slash in Python replace()

Tags: python, string, replace

I have been working on an anagram solver in Python 2.7 and came across a curiosity that I haven't been able to find an explanation for. The program reads from a file which contains a list of anagrams in a format like so:

```
#    anagram
#    anagram
#    anagram
.
.
.
etc
```

Reading this directly into a string, Python obviously comments everything out, so I was playing with replace() trying to find a way to strip out the hash characters. Trying...

```
string = file.read().replace('#', '')
```

...would produce an empty string. I tried to use a backslash in front of the hash but goofed and typo'd a forward slash, which gave me the result:

```
string = file.read().replace('/#', '')
string = '#\tanagram\n#\tanagram\n#\tanagram'
```

Stripping out unnecessary characters was a no-brainer at that point and the program works perfectly. However, I'm not content using a line of code that I don't fully understand. I haven't had much luck finding any documentation or code that explains/makes us of something like this, so I'm either looking in the wrong places or looking for the wrong thing.

Could anyone offer an explanation to why it behaves like this?

Comment: in your second example `replace` just doesn't replace anything and returns an original string, because in your file you don't have `/#` sequence.

Comment: # is only special to Python in source code, not in strings read from a file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[s.lstrip('#\t') for s in file.read().split('\n')]
```

Python does not treat a # specially in any way whatsoever inside a string, you don't need to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change anything else when you replaced your `'#'` with `'/#'`? Try running your program again, exactly as it is, but removing the `/`. `#` isn't a special character in Python strings.

The code you've shown us has a do-nothing in the replace, since there aren't any instances of `'/#'` in your string.

Sample interactive session:

```
>>> "#foo bar\n\t#blah".replace("#", "")
'foo bar\n\tblah'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Nathon. Removing the forward slash like you mentioned results in a blank string. There are no other changes made, also.

Comment: @Vulpine: no repro. Show your actual file content. `replace` returning an empty string is something special.